# camcorderprofile on api16/ jellybean

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, mediarecorder

In my media recorder app, I have

```
 CamcorderProfile cp480=CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_QVGA);
 recorder.setProfile(cp480);
```

It is working fine on API level 15, but for API 16, `cp480` is a `NullPointerException`. Does anyone know what changes in Jelly Bean that could cause this?

Comment: Is this on the device? Emulator? Same device for APIs 15 and 16?

Comment: It is on an emulator run by eclipse. Different device but on api 16 CamcorderProfile.hasProfile() pretty much fails

Comment: And it works on API 15 on the same emulator? Or is the API 15 test on a real device?

Comment: They are generic devices running api 15 and 16 (emulator). I've also set the audio/ video encoder and format manually but that fail on both apis.